# Need help printing on a <td> 2 eval functions for an asp.net image object

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

This is my script to get json from webservice and print SQL data into a html table. Everything is working 100% until I try to print a column for images using Eval functions.

```
<script>

        function GetListaColaboradores() {

            var url = "GetColaboradoresWebService.asmx/GetListaColaboradores";

            $("#AdminUserListPanel").html("<div style='text-align:center; background-color:yellow; border:1px solid red; padding:3px; width:200px'>Please Wait...</div>");

            var request = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            })

            request.done(function (data) {


                var TableContent = "<table id='example1' class='table table-bordered table-striped'>" +
                                    "<thead>" +
                                     "<tr>" +
                                         "<td> Nome </td>" +
                                         "<td> Departamento </td>" +
                                         "<td> Ciclo </td>" +
                                         "<td> Observações </td>" +
                                         "<td> Estado </td>" +
                                         "<td> </td>" +
                                          "<td> </td>" +
                                     "</tr>" +
                                     "</thead>";
                $(function () {
                    $('#example1').DataTable();
                })




                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    TableContent += "<tr>" +
                                            "<td>" + data.d[i].Name + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + data.d[i].Department + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + data.d[i].Profile + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + data.d[i].Observations + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + data.d[i].Status + "</td>" +
                                            "<td style='text-align: center'>" +
                                                '<asp:Image ID="EditIcon" Style="cursor: pointer" ImageUrl="Images/icons8-edit-48.png" Width="15" Height="15" runat="server" />' + 
                                            "</td>"+ 
                                            "<td>" +
                                               "<asp:Image ID='DisableIcon' Width='15' Height='15' ToolTip='Suspender' Style='cursor: pointer' ImageUrl='Images/icons8-unavailable-30.png' runat='server' OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Nome","Javascript:return confirm(\'Deseja suspender o utilizador: {0}\');")%>' Visible='<%# Eval("Descricao").ToString().Replace(" ","")=="Activo" ? true:false %>' />" +
                                               "<asp:Image ID='EnableIcon' Width='15' Height='15' ToolTip='Ativar' Style='cursor: pointer' ImageUrl='Images/icons8-checkmark-30.png' runat='server' OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Nome","Javascript:return confirm(\'Deseja activar o utilizador: {0}\');")%>' Visible='<%# Eval("Descricao").ToString().Replace(" ","")=="Activo" ? false:true %>' />" +
                                            "</td>"+
                                    "</tr>";
                }
                TableContent += "</table>";

                $("#AdminUserListPanel").html(TableContent);


            })
            request.fail(function (response) {

            });
        }   

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', GetListaColaboradores, false);
    </script>
```

This is where the problem is. It gives me an error saying server tag is not well formed

```
"<asp:Image ID='DisableIcon' Width='15' Height='15' ToolTip='Suspender' Style='cursor: pointer' ImageUrl='Images/icons8-unavailable-30.png' runat='server' OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Nome","Javascript:return confirm(\'Deseja suspender o utilizador: {0}\');")%>' Visible='<%# Eval("Descricao").ToString().Replace(" ","")=="Activo" ? true:false %>' />" +
                                               "<asp:Image ID='EnableIcon' Width='15' Height='15' ToolTip='Ativar' Style='cursor: pointer' ImageUrl='Images/icons8-checkmark-30.png' runat='server' OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Nome","Javascript:return confirm(\'Deseja activar o utilizador: {0}\');")%>' Visible='<%# Eval("Descricao").ToString().Replace(" ","")=="Activo" ? false:true %>' />" +
```

I tried to replace

```
'Deseja activar o utilizador: {0}\'
```

to

```
"Deseja activar o utilizador: {0}\"
```

and it will load the page without showing me any errors but it won't print my table so I don't know what else to do anymore, I tried to replace as many double quotes with single quotes and no success. Perhaps there is a better way to do this without using Eval function?

Answer (score 0):

You should try escaping the duble quotes with \"

Comment: In which part of the instruction should i do this? The part where it's giving error already has the \'  which gives the server error thing unless I change it to \" but then no data will be printed

Comment: i think your are printingout a string yep? so the whole image is in a double quoted string.. in your image u are writing Eval("Nome" and something other without escape

Comment: Can you please give me an example how should i do it